# Passing a type to a generic method from an array of types

Tags: swift, generics

I will try to demonstrate what I mean with an example.

Say I have this protocol:

```
protocol P {}
```

And these types that are conforming to it:

```
struct S1 : P {}
struct S2 : P {}
```

And finally, this generic method that accepts one parameter which is any type conforming to protocol P:

```
func f<T>(type: T.Type) where T : P {
    // ...
}
```

Now there is no problem in passing `S1.self` or `S2.self` to `f`.

```
f(type: S1.self) // No problem!
f(type: S2.self) // No problem!
```

But if I want to add `S1.self` and `S2.self` to an array

```
let types: [P.Type] = [S1.self, S2.self]
```

I won't be able to pass to `f` a type from this array.

```
f(type: types[0]) // ERROR: Cannot invoke 'f' with an argument list of type '(type: P.Type)'
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is related to [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33112559/1187415) and unrelated to arrays. `let t: P.Type = S1.self ; f(type: t)` would not compiler either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift needs to be able to determine the type of the generic function at compile time. A call to a generic function gets turned into a explicit call handling only a single type. You are trying to turn that into a runtime decision which will not work.

If you want to call `f(type:)` with a value from your array, you will have to establish its type before making the generic call.

For example, this can be done with a `switch`:

```
switch types[0] {
case let type as S1.Type:
    f(type: type)
case let type as S2.Type:
    f(type: type)
default:
    break
}
```

or with an `if case let`:

```
if case let type as S1.Type = types[0] {
    f(type: type)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible for function arguments. Because using generic `T: P` is like: I don't know what type it has but it must conform to `P`. The compiler infer the type when you pass an argument to the function.

So the problem is with the **array** of generics you used. It can fill array but when you call some index of the array, It will return An **Unknown Type** conformed to `P`. So it **can not infer the generic Type `T`** from it

So you should tell it your self what type is it:

```
f(type: types[0] as! S1.Type)
```

And if you don't know what type is it, you can check it before calling the function:

```
switch types[0] {
case is S1.Type: f(type: types[0] as! S1.Type)
case is S2.Type: f(type: types[0] as! S2.Type)
default: break
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.